Neovim : Display total search occurrences in status line when count exceeds 999
I am using Neovim (0.10.2) with the "lualine" plugin.
I know how to display searchcount on the status line, which works for up to 999 occurrences.
However, I would like to know how to display the occurrence count when the total number of matches is much larger, such as 30k occurrences.
Note: I tried using the "nvim-hlslens" plugin and configured nearest_float_when = 'always', but I don't want the virtual text jumping left and right on the status line.
